# How to Avoid Masterpage's url rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, master-pages

I have a masterpage in the root directory of my site.
Then in another directory, I have a web form that is set to use this masterpage.

The problem is that when the page is shown, all the Urls from the masterpages get rewritten.

For example:

- Base Url in masterpage: "users.aspx"
- Rewritten Url for web pages in "Other" directory: "other/users.aspx"

Is there an option to keep the base URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the urls are being rewritten, it's that you are using relative paths in your master page. You're probably doing something like this:

```
<a href='users.aspx'>View users</a>
```

You can do one of two things, either use absolute paths or use the tilda (`~`) character in your path (although this requires a runat='server'):

```
<a href='/users.aspx'>View users</a>
```

or

```
<a href='~/users.aspx' runat='server'>View users</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I was using the tilda but it was not working. I missed the runat="server", it works now